# Debugging Hadoop Job inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I am using eclipse to build my hadoop job, running on Ubuntu.

The problem is that when i make some mistake, like not inform a parameter to my job, the eclipse doesnt throw an exception. I am not using any plugin, and my files ares in local filesystem.

I am running Hadoop 2.41.

Getting `job.getStatus().getFailureInfo()`, just return NA.

Is it better try MRUnit?

EDIT:

I run the job using the command line and now I see the exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable cannot be cast to identity.CPFPair
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable cannot be cast to identity.CPFPair
```

But my problem still persists. Why can i not see this exception in eclipse console?

Comment: I really dont know how i solved thre problem. I installed everything again in a new VM and it is working now! I suspect that some configuration in eclipse was wrong. I was using Kepler version and now i am using Luna.